# Create a chart using worksheet data in an array variable

Tags: excel, vba

Code to create a chart using data in worksheet.

Basically create a scatter line graph with X axis values in array "TimeArr" and Y axis values in array "TempArr".

Run time error is thrown while assigning values.

```
Sub Chart1()
Dim LupCol, LupRow, LastCol, LastRow As Integer
LupCol = 2
LupRow = 2
LastCol = lCol
rcount = 92
LastRow = rcount - 1

Worksheets("Process_Data").Activate
Dim TimeArr(), TempArr() As Variant
Dim SXvalues, SYvalues As Series
TimeArr = Range(Cells(LupRow, LupCol), Cells(LastRow, LupCol))
TempArr = Range(Cells(LupRow, LupCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LupCol + 1))

Dim ChartSheet1 As Chart
Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear

With ChartSheet1
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Air Side Temperatures"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time"             
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature in degC" 
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = TimeArr 'RUN TIME ERROR of invalid parameter
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = TempArr
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to add a new series before assigning your X and Y values (ie. `.SeriesCollection.NewSeries`).

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit, and it runs just fine, and I've added a few friendly notes to help with your programming:

```
Sub Chart1()
  Dim LupCol As Long, LupRow As Long, LastRow As Long
  ' note: use Long not Integer, long story, but it's better with no drawbacks
  ' also, need to dim each variable as a type, or they'll be variants
  Dim rCount As Long
  LupCol = 2
  LupRow = 2
  rCount = 92
  LastRow = rCount - 1

  Dim TimeArr As Variant, TempArr As Variant
  With Worksheets("Process_Data")
    ' don't need to activate the sheet, just reference it
    ' also, use .Value to populate the arrays
    TimeArr = .Range(.Cells(LupRow, LupCol), .Cells(LastRow, LupCol)).Value
    TempArr = .Range(.Cells(LupRow, LupCol + 1), .Cells(LastRow, LupCol + 1)).Value
  End With

  Dim ChartSheet1 As Chart
  Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add
  ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear

  With ChartSheet1
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      ' need to add series before you populate it
      .XValues = TimeArr
      .Values = TempArr
    End With
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Air Side Temperatures"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature in degC"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0
  End With
End Sub
```

Any reason you want to use hard-coded arrays rather than worksheet ranges as chart data?

To use the ranges:

```
Sub Chart2()
  Dim LupCol As Long, LupRow As Long, LastRow As Long
  Dim rCount As Long
  LupCol = 2
  LupRow = 2
  rCount = 92
  LastRow = rCount - 1

  Dim TimeArr As Range, TempArr As Range
  With Worksheets("Process_Data")
    Set TimeArr = .Range(.Cells(LupRow, LupCol), .Cells(LastRow, LupCol))
    Set TempArr = .Range(.Cells(LupRow, LupCol + 1), .Cells(LastRow, LupCol + 1))
  End With

  Dim ChartSheet1 As Chart
  Set ChartSheet1 = Charts.Add
  ActiveChart.ChartArea.Clear

  With ChartSheet1
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      .XValues = TimeArr  'RUN TIME ERROR of invalid parameter
      .Values = TempArr
    End With
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Air Side Temperatures"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Temperature in degC"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0
  End With
End Sub
```